# If else statement is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

If else command is not working code gets break when else condition is executed. When product is added to cart sometimes it displays that cart is empty and sometimes product gets added to the cart. I wanted to automate this scenario that if cart is empty then it should navigate back to product listing add product in cart again else if cart is not empty then proceed to checkout.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Your cart is empty')]")).isDisplayed()) 
{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("xyz");
            driver.navigate().back();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='list-product-card-inner']//div[2]//div[4]//button//i")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='list-product-card-inner']//div[2]//button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse navbar-collapse']//ul//li[8]//a//i")).click();
          
            Actions in = new Actions((WebDriver) driver);
            WebElement dClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/div[1]/button[2]/i[1]"));
            in.doubleClick(dClick).perform();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        else

            {
                System.out.println("working fine");
            }
```

Comment: Sure sounds like an while true loop doesn't it

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: You are repeatedly doing the same action until the element is not there.

Comment: how to resolve?